# aiohttp and aiohttp_jinja2 response error

Tags: python, jinja2, aiohttp

I'm trying to combine `jinja2` and `aiohttp` using `aiohttp_jinja2` but it turns out that's such a mistake.

I was trying to do in accordance with the [documentation](http://aiohttp-jinja2.readthedocs.org/en/stable/).

Without `jinja2` `aiohttp` operating normally.

`environment`:

```
env
  |_index.py
  |_index.tpl
```

`index.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import asyncio
from aiohttp import web #pip install aiohttp 
import aiohttp_jinja2   #pip install aiohttp_jinja2
import jinja2           #pip install jinja2


@aiohttp_jinja2.template('index.tpl')
@asyncio.coroutine
def page(req):
    response = aiohttp_jinja2.render_template('index.tpl', req,{'k':'v'})
    return response

@asyncio.coroutine
def init(loop):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('./'))
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', page)
    srv = yield from loop.create_server(app.make_handler(), '127.0.0.1', 80)
    return srv

app = web.Application()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
try: loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:  pass
```

Traceback error:

```
Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aiohttp/server.py", line 240, in start
    yield from handler
  File "/home/user/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 69, in handle_request
    resp = yield from handler(request)
  File "/home/user/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aiohttp_jinja2/__init__.py", line 66, in wrapped
    app_key=app_key, encoding=encoding)
  File "/home/user/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aiohttp_jinja2/__init__.py", line 38, in _render_template
    text = template.render(context)
  File "/home/user/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 964, in render
    vars = dict(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use either `template()` decorator or `render_template()` function, never mix the both together.